# Interval containing specified percent of values

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

With numpy or scipy, is there any existing method that will return the endpoints of an interval which contains a specified percent of the values in a 1D array? I realize that this is simple to write myself, but it seems like the kind of thing that might be built in, although I can't find it.

E.g:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.randn(100000)
>>> print(np.bounding_interval(x, 0.68))
```

Would give [approximately](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) `(-1, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`np.percentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

```
In [29]: x = np.random.randn(100000)

In [30]: p = 0.68

In [31]: lo = 50*(1 - p)

In [32]: hi = 50*(1 + p)

In [33]: np.percentile(x, [lo, hi])
Out[33]: array([-0.99206523,  1.0006089 ])
```

There is also [`scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile.html):

```
In [34]: scoreatpercentile(x, [lo, hi])
Out[34]: array([-0.99206523,  1.0006089 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in function to do it, but you can write one using the math package to specify approximate indices like this:

```
from __future__ import division
import math
import numpy as np

def bound_interval(arr_in, interval):
    lhs = (1 - interval) / 2  # Specify left-hand side chunk to exclude
    rhs = 1 - lhs  # and the right-hand side
    sorted = np.sort(arr_in)
    lower = sorted[math.floor(lhs * len(arr_in))]  # use floor to get index
    upper = sorted[math.floor(rhs * len(arr_in))]
    return (lower, upper)
```

On your specified array, I got the interval `(-0.99072237819851039, 0.98691691784955549)`. Pretty close to `(-1, 1)`!